# Ubuntu RAID 1 Booting

Tags: ubuntu, operating-systems, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu using RAID 1. In this case I have 2 harddisks with equal size to be used for RAID. I've been able to configure RAID 1 when installing

```
localhost:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid5] [raid4] [raid6] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[2](F)
  24418688 blocks [2/1] [U_]

 md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
  24418688 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

`/dev/md0` is mounted in `/` and `/dev/md1` mounted in `/home`, but the problem is when I plugged off one harddisk, I can't boot my Ubuntu anymore. I think the problem is because the boot loader is installed in the harddisk (in my case in `/dev/sda`) and not on the RAID device `/dev/md0`.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when when I plugged off the harddisk that has the bootloader, the OS can't boot. So how do I make my Ubuntu use the RAID 1 system so it can still boot in case one of the harddisks is plugged off?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 alternate.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to install the bootloader to both devices, so that both can be booted of. Run the `grub-install` command for each drive in the array.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Secondly, Ubuntu by default won't automatically boot a degraded array (i.e. an array where not all the disks are present). It will prompt you to choose whether to continue booting if the array is degraded -- if you need this to happen automatically:

1. Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm`
2. Set `BOOT_DEGRADED=true`
3. Run `update-initramfs -u` to regenerate the initrd